# Github - how to respond to requested changes after PullRequest and see changes?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, resolve, review

I am very new to git/github and did a pull request to another (their) repo which they didn`t accept and requested changes. How can I send changes to their repo? This is what I did:

- git: I cloned a repo
- git: branched from my *master* to repo *m*
- git: in repo *m* I did changes in 3 files
- git: I added & committed changes ( git add, git commit)
- git: I did:  git push master m
- git: I send a pull request to original repo
- github: They requested changes in 3 files & send Commit suggestion for some changes
- github: I clicked *"Commit suggestion"*

After *"Commit suggestion"*:  **Where are my changes made to? Can I see them somewhere?**

- in my repo m?
- in my master?
- in their repo?

Among the requested changes there was one without a button *"Commit suggestion"* or *"Add suggestion to batch"*
**How can I send changes to their repo?**

Comment: Your description of what you did is incoherent. Step 1: You cloned? Or did you fork? Big difference.  Step 2: "branched from my master to repo m" What does that mean? Step 3: let's wait until you've clarified 1 and 2

Comment: Normally the way to respond to request for changes in pull request branch that you pushed is to make the changes and push again. So we need to understand your architecture to work out why you can't just do that.

Comment: at first I did git clone theirs

Comment: secondly I did git branch m  , git checkout m

Comment: So there is no "repo m". Everyplace your question says "repo m" is a lie. There is your local clone of their repo, and you are on a _branch_ called m. Is that right?

Comment: Also you claim you said "git push master m" at one point. Really? That hardly seems like valid Git. What did Git say in response?

Comment: On Github:  I did fork. So I have a repo there. When I open it I see my m.

Comment: Sorry, the list of steps is still too incoherent for me to understand what you mean. Your bulleted steps in your question never mention a fork; now suddenly you introduce one. How does it fit into the story you told initially? The code `git push master m` is not Git. The phrase "send pull request" is unclear. Please take some time to rewrite your question using true and meaningful descriptions of what you did.